# warning: BREAKPOINT is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java, netbeans-7, compiler-warnings

Netbeans 7.4 on Win7 64b

Big project, when we "Clean & Build" we get the following warning

```
C:\Users\gbarbieri\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EC_400_BETA\src\ec\gui\main\EC_GUI.java:7: warning: BREAKPOINT is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
 *  REKNOW GmbH & Co.KG
```

The line is at the begin, 7, and is pointing to a comment

If I remove the comment, the warning points always at 7, no matter what is there..

Do you have any idea about?

Let's say it is not critical, just a warning, but I am scared it might come from some error that does not show up directly, but is causing somehow, let's call, this collateral effect..

Comment: It looks like the class you are editing is not the same as which is used at compile-time. Otherwise I don't see any reason why the line wouldn't change. Can you post the code?

Comment: You probably want t show a small bit of context around the line, as it sounds like it's reacting to some `@Decorations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this strange import in an another class

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.BREAKPOINT;

Removed that, the warning disappeared